# Rails -- Would like to create a controller with a dash or underscore in name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, naming-conventions

I wanted to create some basic html pages to add to my rails app.

I figured the restful way to do it would be to create a controller.  The problem is I'd like the pages to be a two word title. => ex. `www.example.com/foo-bar/`

For SEO reasons it really must be two words, and I need the separation, using `www.example.com/foobar/` would be a last resort

The problem is I cant `script/generate controller foo-bar` because the of the dash.

Is there any kind of workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does an underscore work for you? You can simply:

```
$ script/generate controller foo_bar
```

Your controller class name will be `FooBarController`, and the default route would map it to something like `http://www.example.com/foo_bar/abc...`.

Comment: thanks that made it the controller.... but whenever I try to go to www.mydomain.com/foo_bar...I get the the routing error page where theres "No route matches "/foo_bar" with {:method=>:get}"